# Why is it okay to write acos(1.0) but not okay to write acos(1)?

Tags: swift, foundation

In Swift, if you have two variables :

```
var a:Int = 2
var b:Double = 3.4
```

And if you try to do :

```
var c = a+b
```

It will trigger an compile-time error, because you cannot add two variables that aren't of the same type.

But still, you could do :

```
var c = b+2
```

It would work because 2, by itself, doesn't have any type, so even if it isn't a decimal number (I mean, I din't wrote 2.0), it stills work.

**Now, here is my question, why doesn't the same principle applies when I do :**

```
acos(1)
```

But it works when I do :

```
acos(1.0)
```

**I see that acos() can take Double, Float, and CGFloat as an argument, but shouldn't Xcode infer that 1 is in fact a Double ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question.  Note that if I define my own function `myAcos` that takes a `Double`, I can call it with `myAcos(1)`:

```
func myAcos(d: Double) -> Double {
    return 0.0
}

let a = myAcos(1)   // This works
```

Now, if I add a second `myAcos` that takes and returns a `Float`:

```
func myAcos(f: Float) -> Float {
    return 0.0
}
```

The call to `myAcos(1)` now give the error: **error: ambiguous use of 'myAcos'**

Then, I add a third function `myAcos` that takes and returns a `CGFloat`:

```
func myAcos(c: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}
```

The call to `myAcos(1)` then gives the error: **error: could not find an overload for 'myAcos' that accepts the supplied arguments**

If I then add a fourth `myAcos` function that takes and returns an `Int`, then `myAcos(1)` works:

```
func myAcos(i: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
}

myAcos(1)  // This works, again
```

So, the answer to your question appears to be that you can't call `acos(1)` because Swift can't figure out which version of `acos` you are attempting to call.

Comment: ... and `var c = b+2` compiles because Double conforms to IntegerLiteralConvertible, and the compiler can infer from the context that `2` should be a Double.

Answer (score 1):

The language spec defines (see Literals in [Language Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID410)) that `1` is an Integer literal and Swift doesn't allow implicit type conversion.

This is for good reasons because it makes expressions like

```
3 / 2
```

more unambiguous.

Comment: @Fogmeister Who are you speaking to ?

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise whoever down voted a perfectly good answer. It may not have answered your additional question but it is a correct answer.

Comment: It is correct that Swift does no implicit conversion. But `1` is an *integer literal*, and Double conforms to IntegerLiteralConvertible. For example, `let x : Double = 3/2` compiles and assigns (surprise, surprise!) the value `1.5` to `x`. So this does not explain why `acos(1)` does not compile.

Comment: Yes, this is interesting question. I think you should change @vacawama's answer as accepted from my answer.

Comment: @Fogmeister this is totally irrelevant to the question and thats why I down voted it . Sure it was correct but it is as relevant as saying SF has a lot of fog :D